# JWE Decryption methodology

Tags: jwe

I have JWE encrypted request and response from a mobile application and co-incidently i do have access to private keys stored in mobile app itself. Since i have no devlopement background of nodejs. Can someone tell me detailed steps to decrypt the encrypted traffic. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [Section 5.2 of RFC7516](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7516#section-5.2) is quite clear about that...